# ZeroBrane Debugging Features Grayed Out

Tags: lua, zerobrane, gideros

I'm trying to debug using ZeroBrane, but it's not working out as it's expected to. I looked at all the info - including [this](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging), on how to debug my apps, but nothing works. All the debug buttons are grayed out, and I never get the play button showing up in my code. There must be something I haven't done. Can someone help me out with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you start the debugging outside of the IDE, you should check the instructions for [remote debugging](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging). It may just come down to starting the debugger server (by going to `Project | Start Debugger Server`), but you may want to check other instructions on that page as well.

If you need to debug Gideros apps (as you indicated in the tag), you need to make sure that Gideros is selected as the interpreter (`Project | Lua Interperter | Gideros`).

Comment: All of that I did. I didn't see any other instructions, but I'll look again to see if I missed anything.

Comment: You may want to email (supportATzerobrane.com) the details shown in the output window.

Comment: There isn't much complaint from the output window, since the project runs fine, just all the debug features remain grayed out. I'll give that a try, and see if they can help.

Comment: For those interested this issue is being discussed in [this ticket](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/903).